# Using Case Statement as second part of where clause

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, vbscript

I have a current sql query I am using in vb.net to get some data returned to a datagridview.  I am checking against the year, month and date of the date time picker to get the necessary information returned from the selected table.  My query works fine minus the case statement part to check for specific dates.  Can anyone help me fix this query or suggest an alternative method?

```
"SELECT * FROM " & Me.SelectedTable.SelectedItem.ToString & " 
WHERE(Datepart(yyyy," & colName & ") BETWEEN '" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Year & "' AND '" & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.Year & "' 
AND Datepart(mm," & colName & ") BETWEEN '" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Month & "' AND '" & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.Month & "' 
AND Datepart(dd," & colName & ") <= " & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Day 
& " CASE WHEN Datepart(mm," & colName & ")=" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Month & " 
THEN Datepart(dd," & colName & ") = " & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Day & " 
WHEN Datepart(mm," & colName & ")= " & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.Month 
& " Datepart(dd," & colName & ")= " & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.Day & " 
ELSE Datepart(dd," & colName & ") BETWEEN 1 AND 31 END)"
```

Comment: Your CASE statement isn't formed properly...but it's hard to make out here.  can you set this to a string, and get the value of the string when the SQL is built, and post that SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query is open to SQL injection attacks. You need to fix it by parameterizing your query.

Next, you do not need the `CASE` there: you can express your logic as a composite logical condition.

I changed the query from one that uses a dynamic column name defined by the value of the `colName` variable to use `col` for better readability. I also defined parameters for the values that come from various pickers. You will need to set them on your prepared command before querying.

The part of most interest is at the bottom: I rewrote your `CASE` as a three-part logical condition that evaluates one of three parts based on the settings of `@month1` and `@month2`, which represent the month values from `DateTimePicker1` and `DateTimePicker2`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (Datepart(yyyy, col) BETWEEN @year1 AND @year2
  AND Datepart(mm, col) BETWEEN @month1 AND @month2
  AND Datepart(dd, col) <= @day1
  AND (
          (Datepart(mm, col)=@month1 AND Datepart(dd, col) = @day1)
      OR  (Datepart(mm, col)=@month2 AND Datepart(dd, col) = @day2)
      OR  (Datepart(dd, col) BETWEEN 1 AND 31)
  )
```

Comment: Data "SELECT * FROM TREND002 WHERE(Datepart(yyyy,Time_Stamp) BETWEEN '2013' AND '2013' AND Datepart(mm,Time_Stamp) BETWEEN '5' AND '8' AND Datepart(dd,Time_Stamp) <= 6 CASE WHEN Datepart(mm,Time_Stamp)=5 THEN Datepart(dd,Time_Stamp) = 6 WHEN Datepart(mm,Time_Stamp)= 8 THEN Datepart(dd,Time_Stamp)= 14 ELSE Datepart(dd,Time_Stamp) BETWEEN 1 AND 31 END)" String

Comment: @user1038895 I'm sure you should be able to follow the example and do the conversion by yourself. That's a very useful exercise - once you learn this skill, you wouldn't be able to "unlearn" it :-)

Comment: dasblinkenlight that worked perfectly and makes perfect sense.  Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have just forgotten then "THEN" at the end of your second condition.

So, make it:

```
CASE 
WHEN Datepart(mm," & colName & ")=" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Month & " THEN
        Datepart(dd," & colName & ") = " & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Day & " 

WHEN Datepart(mm," & colName & ")= " & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.Month & " **THEN**
     Datepart(dd," & colName & ")= " & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.Day & " 

ELSE Datepart(dd," & colName & ") BETWEEN 1 AND 31 
END
```

Comment: The error is incorrect syntax near CASE.  I am not sure how the case statement should be changed though I did add the second then that was necessary but that did not fix the issue.